# Using Matplotlib-Patch inside an animation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to generate an empty patch to be able to set data later on. In order to explain my problem better, i will give an example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

x = range(10)
y = [i**2 for i in x]

figure = plt.figure()
ax1 = figure.add_subplot(111, xlim=(0,10), ylim=(0,100))

my_line, = ax1.plot([],[], 'o-')

def init():
    my_line.set_data([], [])
    return my_line,

i = 0

def animate(_):
    global i
    my_line.set_data(x[0:i], y[0:i])
    i = (i+1)%(len(x)+1)   
    return my_line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(figure, animate, repeat=True, blit=True, init_func=init)

plt.show()
```

Now, I to add a shape, which I define its edge points randomly. I need to use the same structure as I used for plotting lines inside the `init()` block: `my_line.set_data([], [])` . However, I couldn't succeed.

I use the same structure as the example provided in the [matplotlib tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/path_tutorial.html) . My `verts` are generated from a function.

When I try using: `foo = patches.PathPatch([], facecolor='red', lw=2, alpha=0.0)` I get
`<matplotlib.patches.PathPatch at 0x335d390>`

But later, I cannot set the path data. I tried using `foo.set_data` and `foo.set_path` but PathPatch doesn't have such attributes and therefore, they didn't work. I checked [this page](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/artist_api.html?highlight=patch) but I couldn't get anywhere. I checked all of the tutorials I could find, but none of them helped.

As a workaround, I used `ax1.add_patch()` command and have set the alpha value to 0. This helped to some extend but, as I have to enter data to be able to use this command, all of the shapes become visible at the final step of the animation for a very short time and, as I save my figure in that moment, it yields unfavorable results.

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what shape you're using, if you use a [polygon](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Polygon), you can update the vertices of a polygon with the set_xy method and create the initial polygon with vertices that are all equal to each other. Example below. If you need a completely arbitrary shape, you might be better off plotting lines and using [fill_between](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/recipes.html) to draw it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import animation

# Create the figure and axis
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 10), ylim=(0, 10))

# mMke the initial polygon with all vertices set to 0
pts = [[0,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0]]
patch = plt.Polygon(pts)
ax.add_patch(patch)

def init():   
    return patch,

def animate(i):
    # Randomly set the vertices
    x1= 5*np.random.rand((1))[0]
    x2= 5*np.random.rand((1))[0] 
    x3= 5*np.random.rand((1))[0] + 5
    x4= 5*np.random.rand((1))[0] + 5

    y1= 5*np.random.rand((1))[0]
    y2= 5*np.random.rand((1))[0] 
    y3= 5*np.random.rand((1))[0] + 5
    y4= 5*np.random.rand((1))[0] + 5

    patch.set_xy([[x1,y1], [x2,y2], [x3,y3], [x4,y4]])

    return patch,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,init_func=init,frames=36,interval=1000,blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I have changed my code a little bit, and now I plot my shape using the polygon-patch. The shape I am using is actually also a polygon but I was defining it in a more indirect way. Thanks a lot for your answer!