# Lidar data Graph

Tags: python, ros, lidar, slam

> SLAM Using RpLiDar and ROS

Hello, I have a table with two columns [Degrees, Distance] and I need to display that info to make a map around my position. Anyone knows a good way to do that, for example every time im in the center and i detect that at 90 degrees is something so i print a dot there.

Im using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Python 2.7.15, ROS melodic and RpLidar A2M8

> Edit

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="polar")
    ax.scatter(infAng,infDist)
    plt.show()
```

Im using this to plot my polar coordinate table, but i dont know how to graph this in real time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your aim is to visualize SLAM and therefore, i assume you want to visualize the particle clouds in real time. The lidar you specify can measure 8000 particles per second. This is not very low and hard to plot with typical python modules such as [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/).

There are several options to which you can refer to:

- [PCL](http://pointclouds.org/) (default approach in ROS)
- [Cloud compare](https://www.danielgm.net/cc/) (this would require you to dump your data in an another format -- maybe `.csv`
- many others...

If you want to stick to python, then you can use [Mayavi](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/), which is faster compared to Matplotlib. You can find an example repository developed for visualizing [KITTI Dataset](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/setup.php) Lidar data [here](https://gist.github.com/ronrest/08abaf42930473f9e3e2dbadad5c92fb).

Comment: I found the polar plots in matplotlib to do this in python, but i dont know how to do this in real time, im gonna edit the question with my updates

Comment: @DanielDaza in matplotlib, you have to do update the canvas. There are lots of examples on that. You can also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22771111/using-matplotlib-patch-inside-an-animation . Keep in mind that in your case, you have to update the data of scatter plot, not the line!